# Impact of unlimited buffer size for dbms.output

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Would like to know, how the system would get impacted when dbms.output(NULL) is set . i.e, buffer size is unlimited.

Also, I have another question.

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE (buffer_size IN INTEGER DEFAULT 20000);
Buffer size can be set between 2000 to 1000000. 
But , what happens if buffer size is set > 1000000. 
For ex: DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(2000000)
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try it and see what happens the memory is stored in PGA,.., so you can easily track your consumption. There is of course limited memory in real life, so ...it depends on that amount!